# JQuery Class Conflict

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script that expands the row below it when you click it, i also have a table sorter jquery which sorts the table

The problem is both use classes on the `<tr>` to work so there is a conflict, i know very little jquery but the expand/collapse row is pretty simple so i was hoping that i can make a small change to this query to avoid the conflict with the sorter jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function(){
    $("#table tr:odd").addClass("odd");
        $("#table tr:not(.odd)").hide();
        $("#table tr:first-child").show();
        $("#table tr.odd").click(function(){
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();

        });
        //$("#table").jExpand();
    });
</script>
```

I might be underestimating how easy it is to fix but if it is easy then that would be great. The table design is just a standard

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can have as many classes as you want on an object.  One part of your code can refer to some of the classes and other parts of your code can refer to other classes.  This does not create a conflict.  What exactly is the problem you are experiencing?  What exactly does not work?

Comment: Are you sure you've got your table markup correct? At the moment it looks like you're closing your rows with `</td>`...

Comment: There some code missing here, sorting in particular.

Comment: @Shaggylnjun What do you mean sorting?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid adding classes in your code, this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function(){
           $("#table tr").not(':odd').hide();
           $("#table tr:first-child").show();
           $("#table tr").filter(':odd').click(function(){
              $(this).next("tr").toggle();

           });
        //$("#table").jExpand();
    });
</script>
```

**Update:**
Use of `.filter()` instead of pseudo-selectors inside jquery selectors, thanks to  **Ohgodwhy**.

Comment: Please don't use `:` methods directly inside of jQuery selectors. You need to select the element and then filter against it, otherwise we can't leverage `querySelectorAll()`. It should be `$('#table tr').filter(':odd').click`.